# Android: How to determine if the number being called is valid or invalid

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I have a big list of opt-in numbers. 
Some of them are bogus or fake.

I need to write a small app that does the following:-

- Read numbers from an excel file
- Call each number: if the call gets through (the phone rings or is busy/engaged), we mark the number as valid in a new column in the excel sheet. If the number is invalid, we mark the number as invalid.

**Is it possible to achieve this in Android?**

**Can we get the response status while making a call from the app?** 
Example: Status=Ringing, Status=Busy/Engaged, Status=Invalid etc

Is there a better way of finding if a phone number is valid or invalid?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You are unable to call any phone number other way than firing out an intent to invoke device's Phone app do the job, therefore full and smooth automation is hardly possible. You may try to do that and at the same time set up own listener to know if the call succeeded or not, but that's far from what you wanted.

Comment: Okay thanks, but can we use this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in Android but you can develop it in a cloud-based IVR system using [Call Control XML (CCXML)](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/) and a platform that has good call progress analysis, like [Voxeo](http://evolution.voxeo.com/). Take a look at [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176290/check-to-see-if-telephone-number-is-active-real) which provides more detail. Be careful with this type of solution as there are laws which govern automatic notification. Make sure people opt in for this type of notification/verification.

Comment: Yes, so I figured. 
I am planning to use a "Do no Disturb" filter released by the Telecom Regulatory Authority of my country to honor the same. 
The numbers are opt-in, but I'd still like to make this as unintrusive as possible.